# Loading a core dump from a cross-compiled executable that crashes in a sharedobject

Tags: gdb, shared-libraries, cross-compiling, coredump

I have the trifecta of gdb complications to untangle. My executable is cross-compiled from x64 to arm, it uses shared objects and the crash is located in one (I know because I added the crash in on purpose), and this is a core dump.

I'm using gdb-multiarch 9.2, but I also have a much older arm-unknown gdb 6.8 available that comes with the toolchain. I can happily get a backtrace if I link  static versions of the libs. I pass "-Wl,--build-id" to the linker for all targets and save the unstripped elf/.so to a local .build-id folder in the correct dir structure.

The problems arise when using shared objects. GDB is unable to map the stack addresses to any symbol.

"(gdb) info shared" yields

```
Cannot access memory at address 0x84c
```

on the toolchain gdb.

On gdb-multiarch, I get

```
Cannot access memory at address 0x84c
Cannot access memory at address 0x848
No shared libraries loaded at this time.
```

I can only assume 0x84c is the non-relocated load address of one of the shared objects.

Here's how I invoke gdb:

```
# gdb-multiarch -ex "set debug-file-directory ." -ex "set sysroot /usr/local/DigiEL-5.9/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/" my-exec my-exec-11-1637064196.core
```

I'm unsure whether I need to pass the sysroot here, but my local ld-linux.so and the remote one are definitely different and might not load .so at the same address.

I tried loading the unstripped .so with "file", which changes nothing.

I would welcome any debugging tips to understand why gdb fails to find the symbols.

Comment: Does anything change if you remove the `my-exec-11-1637064196.core` from command line, and use `(gdb) core my-exec-11-1637064196.core` instead?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I am able to get a good backtrace if I remote debug the issue, by also setting the solib-search-path, but this is not working for the core dump.

How do I find out what addr the sharedobjects were loaded at from a core dump? Maybe it could help me by using add-symbol-file with a manually input address.

Comment: Is the executable `PIE` and if so, does the problem persist if you link it with `-no-pie`?

Comment: Good idea. I tried with PIE enabled and disabled, no difference :/